# efficient way to query similar sentences

Tags: c++, string, performance

I have a task need to find similar sentences from the memory. The task read input file containing:

```
a b c
c d e f
f h g w
.............
```

and then, given a new query, ex

```
h g w
```

the return should be

```
f h g w
```

which is the line in the input file containing all the query words.

I would like to know how to efficiently store the input sentence so that it can be used for query efficiently.

Comment: Why do you want to know that?, is your code inefficient?

Comment: I need some ideas to handle this task. I don't think to search it line by line is a solution.

Comment: I have no code yet, just starting

Comment: Then what is a solution? Normally comparing strings stops when the first difference happens so that's efficient. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, if you have some code and it has issues then you come to this site and ask for help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: but the order in the sentence is not a matter

Comment: Query is only substring ? what should you answer for "c" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the dictionary of words as a vector of strings:

```
vector<string> dict;
```

so in your example, you will put `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` and so on inside the dictionary.

then you can represent a sentence as vector of integers, where the integer is the index of the word in the dictionary:

```
vector<int> sentence;
```

for example the first sentence would be `{0, 1, 2}`.

You can store all the sentences in a vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> sentences;
```

At this point, checking if a subphrase is inside a phrase is exactly the same as the substring search algorithm (provided you convert also the phrase query into a vector of integers).

Comment: thanks, it is a good idea. This is the best as far as I can come up with.